# Configure URLs with prefix in Mojolicious behind Reverse Proxy (ProxyPass)

Tags: apache, perl, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, mojolicious

I'm looking for a reliable way to configure Mojolicious running behind an Apache reverse proxy under /app, so that `url_for('/foo')` actually returns `/app/foo` instead of just `/foo` (otherwise all the links would be broken).

The [documentation](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Apachemod_proxy) shows a reverse proxy example for everything under /. But that's not what I need, since the application should be under /app.
Turning `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/` into `ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/` will cause the issue as the `/app` prefix would be missing from all urls generated by the application.

The documentation also has a [section on rewriting](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Rewriting), which has an example of a before_dispatch hook that will take the first part of the request url and use it as base. This requires the prefix to be appended to the ProxyPass url (`ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/app/` with trailing slash) in the Apache config, which does not seem to be mentioned on that page but maybe it does not need to be ("Move first part and slash from path to base path") because it's obvious. That makes it possible to call `http://localhost/app/page`, which turns into `http://localhost:8080/app/page` ('app' removed by the hook), where `url_for('/foo')` will return `'/app/foo'` (`http://localhost/app/foo`), so the links will be correct (without trailing slash in the ProxyPass rule, that would make `/apppage/foo`).

However, in this example, the url modification is *always* made in production mode (`if app->mode eq 'production'`). So calling the backend server directly (`http://localhost:8080/testpage`) won't work anymore, since all the urls would be broken.

So I thought, I'd check if the `X-Forwarded-For` header is set (by mod_proxy_http) instead, which would always be set for reverse proxy requests. And since the [Apache mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) mentions that this header might already be set in the client request (and end up containing more than one value), I'd remove it from the request first - because a client sending this header should not cause the url base modification.

Apache VirtualHost configuration:

```
# ProxyPreserveHost: Mojo::URL::to_abs() not 127.0.0.1
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location "/app/">
    # ProxyPass: prefix pass-thru
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/app/
    # RequestHeader: must not be set externally
    RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For
</Location>
```

Hook in Mojolicious startup():

```
$self->hook('before_dispatch' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my $behind_proxy = !!$c->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-Host');
    if ($behind_proxy) {
        push @{$c->req->url->base->path->trailing_slash(1)},
            shift @{$c->req->url->path->leading_slash(0)};
        $c->req->url->path->trailing_slash(0) # root 404
            unless @{$c->req->url->path->parts};
    }
});
```

This seems to work...

**Question: Will my approach work reliably in the "real world" or is it flawed?**

Edit:
Requesting the root address (`http://localhost:3000/app/`) through the reverse proxy always resulted in an error 404. So I've added two lines to turn the trailing slash off in that case. Since I can't find that in the docs, there may be a better way.

Comment: You might be interested in using Mojolicious Route Bridge. This way you can easily add /app to all your urls: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Bridges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm now answering my own question as I'm getting more suggestions (not just here) from people who would put a hard-coded prefix in their application code. It should be obvious that prefixing all generated urls manually isn't a solution. Just imagine two instances of the same application deployed on the same server, one under `/app1` and the other under `/app2`. The whole point of the suggested code in my question is that the application works and produces correct urls if accessed through a reverse proxy without breaking requests going directly to the application server. A developer would run Morbo, but a hard-coded prefix would break that. Also, I made at least one mistake in my question, but nobody seems to have noticed.

#### Flaws in code

I had too many slashes in my example in the question.
The way the `Location` block is defined, requests to `/app` without trailing slash would fail. It might be better to write it like that:

```
<Location "/app">
...
```

Next, I wrote that I check for the `X-Forwarded-For` header but I actually checked for `X-Forwarded-Host`. That wouldn't be a problem if I were also clearing that header but I cleared `X-Forwarded-For` instead. With that awkward mistake, the safety mechanism wouldn't work, so if you'd set this header while working with your application server at localhost:3000, the app would try to repair the manipulated url even though it's not supposed to do that.

It should've been:

```
RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Host
```

Example:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location /app>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/app
    RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Host
</Location>
```

The `ProxyPreserveHost` directive isn't required as long as the application uses relative urls everywhere. If the application wants to generate an absolute url, for example `url_for('/page')->to_abs`, `ProxyPreserveHost` should be enabled, otherwise external clients would get `http://localhost:3000/app/page`.

#### Reverse proxy detection

When I wrote that question, I saw the `before_dispatch` hook in the [Mojolicious documentation](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Rewriting) and, as pointed out in the question, I wanted to use it for an application running under `/app`. However, I didn't want to break Morbo. The example assumes that the application is in production mode (`$app->mode`) while running behind a reverse proxy but not when access directly through Morbo, but I didn't want to change the mode for every other request.

That's why I added a condition to check if the request came through a reverse proxy. As this header is only set by Apache (by the [mod_proxy_http module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers)) and not by `Mojo::Server::Morbo`, it can be used as reverse proxy detection. Together with the right directive to clear the `X-Forwarded-Host`, I believe the answer to my question would be that **yes**, that should work reliably.

(Although that last part isn't strictly necessary as long as direct access to the app server is limited to the developer.)

#### Manipulated url

To show why I've added the `/app` prefix to the `ProxyPass` line in the Apache configuration, I'd like to point out that this approach manipulates the url to allow the application to work under the given prefix. There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31864849/664132) of someone who forgot to add the prefix in the Apache configuration and I wrote an [answer explaining what the hook does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208440/664132).

```
Morbo: localhost:3000
Apache reverse proxy: host.com/app or localhost/app

# Browser > Apache:
http://host.com/app
# Apache (ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/) > Mojolicious sees:
GET /
url_for '/test' = /test 
(or even //test if the hook pushes undef, see the other answer linked above)
# Apache (configured as described above) > Mojolicious sees:
GET /app
# Hook:
base = /app
request = /
url_for '/test' = /app/test
```

Normally, the local target argument in the `ProxyPass` directive would not have the prefix, it would just be something like `ProxyPass http://...:3000/`. In that case, the application doesn't know about the prefix, which is why all generated urls and links are incomplete.

This approach requires you to let Apache pass the prefix through to the application server. The application doesn't know about the prefix, so it wouldn't know what to do with a request to `/app/page`. This is where the hook comes in. It assumes that the first level of the path is always the prefix, so it turns `/app/page` into `/page` and it conveniently appends the `/app` prefix to the url base, which is used when generating urls, making sure that a link to `/test` actually points to `/app/test`.

Obviously, this modification should not be done for any request sent directly to Morbo.

#### Alternative

Alternatively, a custom request header could be set by the reverse proxy and then used by the hook to produce working urls. The [Mojolicious::Plugin::RequestBase module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::RequestBase) works that way. It expects you to define the prefix in the X-Request-Base header, not in the url:

```
RequestHeader set X-Request-Base "/app"
```

In that case, the application should only receive requests for urls relative to that prefix:

```
ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
```

All that module really does is pick up the header and use it as url base:

```
$c->req->url->base($url); # url = X-Request-Base = /app
```

Example:

```
<Location /app>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
    RequestHeader set X-Request-Base "/app"
</Location>
```

This is a nice and simply solution. Note that the `/app` prefix appears twice in that case. And of course, the [hook implemented by that module](https://metacpan.org/source/MRAMBERG/Mojolicious-Plugin-RequestBase-0.3/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/RequestBase.pm) only does its work if the `X-Request-Base` header is set, just like the hook shown above does nothing if the `X-Forwarded-Host` header is not set.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set base path for each request url in **before_dispatch** hook

```
$app->hook(before_dispatch => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->req->url->base->path('/app/');
});
```

Example:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

app->hook(before_dispatch => sub {
  shift->req->url->base->path('/app/');
});


get '/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->render(text => $c->url_for('test'));
};

get '/test/url' => sub { ... } => 'test';

app->start;
```

And result:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:3000
/app/test/url
```

Comment: This would **always** prepend the "app" prefix, even for direct requests (curl 127.0.0.1:3000) that don't go through the Apache proxy. But this is not the question. Quoting: `So calling the backend server directly (http://localhost:8080/testpage) won't work anymore, since all the urls would be broken.`

Comment: You can add the prefix 'app' only if request was make via proxy server.

<pre><code>
app->hook(before_dispatch => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->req->url->base->path('/app/') if $self->req->headers->header('Some_header_from_proxy_server');
});
</pre></code>

Comment: Andrey, thanks for trying to help, I really appreciate it - but please take another look at my question. You're suggesting that I check for "some" header. However I thought of this too before I asked the question, I found a specific header ("X-Forwarded-Host") which does not need to be configured because it's set automatically. My question was: **Will my approach work reliably in the "real world" or is it flawed?**

Answer (score 0):

You should mount your application under required path.

In your `startup` you should do:

```
$r =  $app->routes;
$r =  $r->any( '/api' )->partial( 1 );

$r->get( '/test' );
```

You should not configure specially your apache. When `GET /api/test` will come your app will get `/api/test` route. This route partially matched to `/api` and the rest route `/test` will be assigned into `->stash->{ path }`.

So rest routes will be checked against `/test` ([source](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.50/lib/Mojolicious/Routes.pm#L63))

Comment: This doesn't fix urls generated by the application. In addition to the hardcoded prefix in the `any` route, all `url_for` calls would have to have the same prefix added. Also, this has absolutely nothing to do with REST.