# How do I set the base URL for my proxied app?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I need to place a Mojolicious app behind an Apache reverse proxy. I've been unable to get Mojolicious to generate working URLs when behind the proxy.

I'm using Mojolicious 6.14 with Perl 5.18.1.

Here's my Apache reverse proxy configuration which I set based on https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment (in the path section).

```
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:3000/ keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:3000/

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-HTTPS "0"
```

Here's my test case.

```
use 5.014;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

app->hook('before_dispatch' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  if ($self->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-Host')) {
    #Proxy Path setting
    my $path = shift @{$self->req->url->path->parts};
    push @{$self->req->url->base->path->parts}, $path;
  }
});

any '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render('index');
};

any '/test' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render('test');
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Index Page</title></head>
<body>
  <p>Index page</p>
  <p>
  %= link_to 'Go to Test Page' => '/test'
  </p>
</body>
</html>

@@ test.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test Page</title></head>
<body>
  <p>Test page</p>
  <p>
  %= link_to 'Return to home page' => '/'
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see the index page when I access http://www.example.com/app1, but the link to the test page is incorrect. The link is `//test` when I expected it to be `http://www.example.com/app1/test`.

Here's the HTML output from the test case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Index Page</title></head>
<body>
  <p>Index page</p>
  <p>
  <a href="//test">Go to Test Page</a>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I tell Mojolicious what the base URL is for my app so it generates the correct links?

Comment: I believe this is answered here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571608/configure-urls-with-prefix-in-mojolicious-behind-reverse-proxy-proxypass

Answer (score 1):

Maybe need to replace server proxy pass on `http://localhost:3000/app1` in apache config:

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:3000/app1 keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:3000/app1
```

Comment: You're on the right track! Unfortunately, you haven't explained *why* it needs to be written like that to make this particular hook work. It may be different in other cases. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208440/664132) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question! Judging by some of the answers here and elsewhere, there seems to be a general lack of understanding of how the Apache reverse proxy settings affect the Mojolicious application and what the hook is supposed to do.

You've received an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31876653/664132) that's basically correct, but it begins with "*Maybe* [need to replace server proxy pass..." and it doesn't provide any explanation. A trial-and-error approach may or may not work for you. If your hook works differently, it probably won't.

#### Apache reverse proxy

This is your reverse proxy configuration (trailing slash removed, see below):

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:3000 keepalive=On
```

Quoting from the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> Suppose the local server has address http://example.com/; then
>
> | ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/
>
> will cause a local request for http://example.com/mirror/foo/bar to be internally converted into a proxy request to http://backend.example.com/bar.

Now, assuming your Apache is listening on localhost:80 and your (Morbo) application server is listening on port 3000, a request to `http://localhost/app1` is received by the Apache and forwarded to your application as `/`. The `app1` prefix has been lost, which is why it's missing from the base url, i.e., it's missing in all the links. To fix urls generated by the application, this prefix must be added to the base url, which leads us to the hook.

#### Hook

This is your hook function:

```
if ($self->req->headers->header('X-Forwarded-Host')) { # 1. if
    my $path = shift @{$self->req->url->path->parts}; # 2. shift
    push @{$self->req->url->base->path->parts}, $path; # 3. push
}
```

This hook is supposed to fix the base url. As explained above, the `app1` prefix needs to be added to the base url, which is prepended to all generated urls. If one of your templates links to `/test`, the base url should look like `/app1` to get the final url `/app1/test`.

This is what your hook does:

1. By checking for the X-Forwarded-Host, you make sure to *only* modify the base url if the request came through the reverse proxy. This works because the [mod_proxy_http module (documentation)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) automatically sets that header. Without that check, you wouldn't be able to access your application server directly under localhost:3000, all urls would be broken.

   In fact, I asked the [question on how this distinction should be made in a reliable way to fix the url prefix when using a reverse proxy without breaking requests going to the application server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23571608/664132). Unfortunately, most of the answers I have received are wrong. But I believe checking for X-Forwarded-Host is good enough as it's set by Apache and not by Morbo or Hypnotoad. In fact, it's set by reverse proxies, which is precisely what you're looking for.
2. This `shift` is supposed to extract the prefix from the request url.

   This is necessary because, strictly speaking, appending the application prefix to the `ProxyPass` directive manipulates the final request url, so your application receives a request for `/app1/`. Of course, there's no route for that address because the router in your application doesn't know that `/app1` is the prefix of that instance rather than a relative application url.

   Clearly, adding the hard-coded prefix `/app1` to all templates (as some might be tempted to do) would not work if you deployed another copy of the same application under `/app2`. Even if you didn't, you'd still have to change all the links if your provider forces you to change the `app1` prefix to `app_one`. This is why the prefix is picked up in that hook, stored to make links work (see #3) and then removed from the request url to make the router happy.
3. This is where the `/app1` prefix, a single path token, is *appended* to the base url. The base url is *prepended* to urls generated in your templates. This is what turns `/test` into `/app1/test` (if the request came through the reverse proxy).

   In your case, `/test` is turned into `//test` because you're missing the prefix. I've explained that at the end of this answer.

#### Fix reverse proxy

That being said, your reverse proxy needs to manipulate the request url to include the prefix in order to make the hook work:

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:3000/app1
```

After this modification, your hook works:

1. It modifies the base url *only if* a reverse proxy header is set because the modification is only necessary when a reverse proxy is used.
2. All requests going to the Mojolicious application will have the `/app1` prefix, e.g., `/app1/test`. In this step, the prefix is removed to turn the url into `/test`.
3. The prefix removed in step 2 is appended to the base url, which is later used to generate links.

This should explain *why* you need to add the application prefix to the `ProxyPass` line. Without that explanation, someone else might try to do just that without success because they might have a different hook function.

#### Slashes

A single slash can break everything and cause most requests to fail with error 404.

Note that the local target url in your `ProxyPass` line (second argument) has a trailing slash but the path argument doesn't. If those don't match, you might end up with double slashes in the request url and some requests could fail.

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.

Now, if you remove the trailing slash but forget the prefix...

```
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:3000
```

... generated urls will still have two leading slashes: `url_for '/test'` = `//test`
That's because you're appending `undef` to the base url where you want to append the application prefix.

What happens is that in step 2 (see above), you extract the prefix, assuming the application is running exactly one level below the document root, i.e., your prefix is something like `app1` and not `apps/app1` (in which case the shift/push routine has to be run twice). But there's no prefix in the ProxyPass directive, so your application sees something like `/`, in other words, there's nothing to extract from `parts`. And there's no safeguard in the code either, so you end up pushing `undef` to the parts array of the base url. If you then generate a url, Mojolicious is adding an extra slash for that `undef` element, which is why you get `//test`. The parts array looks like this:

```
"parts" => [
  undef,
  "test"
],
```

To fix this double slash error, you can add a safeguard to your hook:

```
my $path = shift @{$self->req->url->path->parts};
if ($path) { # safeguard
    push @{$self->req->url->base->path->parts}, $path;
}
```

Of course, as long as your reverse proxy configuration has the prefix in it, `$path` should always be defined.

One could certainly argue that this approach is a hack because it manipulates the url. Hacks tend to fail under certain circumstances. In this case, it would fail if you were to manually set the `X-Forwarded-Host` while accessing the application server directly. I mentioned that in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23571608/664132). But as developer, you're probably the only person who has direct access to that application server, as the firewall would only allow external requests to the reverse proxy in a typical production environment. I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow a workaround, but this is how I solved this problem:

In the configuration-file (`.conf`) I define the the base-url:

```
base_url => 'https://booking.business-apartments.wien',
```

This allows me to write templates like this:

```
%= link_to 'Payment Information' => ( config('base_url') . url_for('intern/invoice/list_payments/') );
```

Answer (score -1):

May you should try to update your Mojolicious to a newer version? I remember I had a similar problem and I solved it with a code where I explicitly defined the url for the proxy and appended it to every request (similar to lanti's answer). After some mojolicious update the code was not necessary anymore.
Moreover, I think I use the same config as proposed by Logioniz.

Comment: I have downvoted this because it doesn't answer the question. This is not about the Mojolicious version. Even if there was a related change in Mojolicious, how should the app know about the prefix if it's never even passed to the app?

Comment: The proxy prefix is passed to an application from the server (Apache, Nginx). I just recall, that in some older versions this information was ignored and custom implementation was necessary (similar to the one presented by you @basic6). After an update (unfortunately, I don't remember which one), this was not longer the case, so thus an update might have helped at the time the question was posted (2015).

Answer (score -1):

When you mount your app into some point (not root / ) it is curious to get working it. Look at Mojolicious::Controller::url_for

```
  # Make path absolute
  my $base_path = $base->path;
  unshift @{$path->parts}, @{$base_path->parts};
  $base_path->parts([])->trailing_slash(0);
```

Here you can control what is generated.

Comment: I have downvoted this because you're not answering the question at all. Are you suggesting that people modify the code of the `url_for` sub by adding a hard-coded prefix in there? So each app instance would have to pick up a specifically modified Mojolicious, which would be replaced with the next update anyway. That's terrible advice, never ever do that. The op missed something in the Apache configuration.